# CoreBluetooth Characteristic value being overwritten to nil

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift4, core-bluetooth

I've created a Bluetooth delegate and have Bluetooth connecting correctly.

In my Bluetooth object I have called the required function:

```
// Characteristic being targeted
var writeCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic!

public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, 
    didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
    guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else {
        return
    }
    print(characteristics)
    for characteristic in characteristics {
        switch (characteristic.uuid) {
        case (serialUUID) :
            print("serialPortRXCharacterUUID: \(service.uuid)")
            writeCharacteristic = characteristic  
        default:
            print("nothing")
        }
    }
}
```

Checking the debugger `writeCharacteristic` stores the correct characteristic however when I call the `writeToDevice` in my ViewController.

```
// View Controllers function
@IBAction func writeToDevice(_ sender: UIButton) {
    bluetoothManager.writeToPeripheral(message: "Test", peripheral: peripheral)
}
```

The `writeToDevice` function gets called in the Bluetooth class object as follows:

```
func writeToPeripheral(message: String, peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    if let data = message.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        let datareturn = String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print(writeCharacteristic)
        peripheral.writeValue(data, for: writeCharacteristic!, type: .withoutResponse)
    }
}
```

Following the debugger `writeCharacteristic` goes from a value when the device connects, but after I call the button from the other view controller, the `writeCharacteristic` seems to go back to `nil`.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same instance of your Bluetooth class?

Comment: @Paulw11 I do call BluetoothLE.init() again in this new ViewController and then delegate it to the "New ViewControllers's" self. I'm guessing this would create a new instance wouldn't it?...

Comment: Indeed. I'd suggest to use a Singleton for your `BluetoothLE`.

Comment: can you check if contains write permission like 
writeCharacteristic.properties.contains(.write) ?

Answer (score 0):

Following @Larme's comment, I realised I was creating a second instance of the BLE object hence implementing a singleton pattern will resolve this issue.